# "Statically linking" a typescript library with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a project with an Angular Frontend, a CLI frontend and a core set of files that are independent from Angular. Currently I create the Angular Application via the Angular CLI and the CLI frontend via a standalone `tsconfig.json` from the same directory tree:

```
angular-client/src/main.ts        // Angular entry point
angular-client/src/main.cli.ts    // CLI entry point
angular-client/src/core/index.ts  // Doesn't use any Angular imports
```

So I basically have two applications in the same source tree. This worked fine until now where I want to add another API frontend using e.g. Nest.js. I would therefore like to split up my project structure "properly" using 4 distinct folders:

```
core/index.ts                  // Doesn't use any Angular imports
angular-client/src/main.ts     // Angular entry point
cli-app/main.ts                // CLI entry point
api-app/main.ts                // API webserver entry point
```

I discovered npm workspaces and they seemed to be the solution to my problem: After setting them up I can compile the Angular application just fine. But when I run the application every function of my core library isn't available. It seems that the Typescript compiler is happily finding my type definitions from the `core` folder but is not "linking" the actual JavaScript code into the generated Angular application. I have a [minimal project available on GitHub](https://github.com/MarcusRiemer/question-angular-library) and I will try to reproduce the most relevant excerpts here.

```
npm install
cd angular-client
npx ng serve
```

If you now surf to `http://localhost:4200` you will get an error like:

```
ERROR TypeError: core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.libraryFunction is not a function
```

```
// @file package.json
// Setting up workspaces
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "angular-client",
    "core"
  ]
}
```

```
// @file core/package.json
{
  "name": "core",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "barrelsby": "2.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.2.4"
  }
}
```

```
// @file core/index.ts
export function libraryFunction() {
  console.log("index.ts from library");
}
```

```
// @file angular-client/package.json
// This links to `core/package.json`
{
  "name": "angular-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4",
    "core": "0.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "typescript": "~4.3.2"
  }
}
```

```
// @file angular-client/src/app/app.component.ts
// This uses the `libraryFunction` defined by `core`
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { libraryFunction } from 'core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  libraryFunction = libraryFunction();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.libraryFunction);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could consider a monorepo here instead of re-inventing the wheel. NX is very nice and does all this stuff (and much more) out of the box: https://nx.dev/

Comment: I will consider that after I got it working at least once. Introducing yet another tool on top of the Angular CLI (which builds upon Webpack, which invokes `ngcc`, which uses `tsc`) seems sort of ridiculous for such a task.

Comment: Once you realize the power of NX - I think you will simply ask yourself why you spend so much time getting a custom solution to work :-)